# Script Import Statement not working On placement

Tags: javascript, html, import

For some reason depending on where i put this import statement for my script, it may or may not be detected. I cant figure out why though. The image below shows a script that for some reason is not being detected.

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="sendmessage.js"></script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first script tag is being closed incorrectly:

You are doing:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"/>
```

You should be using:

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.11.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

Comment: @AlecKaczmarek no problem - we all make silly mistakes sometimes

Comment: @AlecKaczmarek could you please mark the answer as correct, So that people know it has been answered? Thanks!